# Correct Way To Implement A Tabbed Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have been browsing the web for a while now and looking at different examples of how to implement a tab bar.

The problem I am having is deciding the correct approach to creating this feature. The option that seems most used is to have one main activity called MainActivity or something and using fragments as the tabs. This is all well and good and I have created an application like this fine.

The problem I am having is I am in two minds as to whether this is the right way to go about it as coming from an iOS development background it just doesn't seem right due to these tabs having different functions.

Any pointers would be great.

**EDIT** I have also looked into ActionBarSherlock but couldn't get to use it in a project as it kept coming up with errors and I couldn't find a thread that sorted the problems I was having out.

Disco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using fragments, yes. There is an example of how to do it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

This "only" works with Tabs that are part of your Actionbar, though. Shouldn't be too much of a problem, because they usually *should* be part of your Actionbar. You can also manually move the tabs if you're not content with their location, or roll your own buttons that look like tabs.

Keep in mind that tabs in Android aren't quite the same beast as the tab bar is in iOS. They look similar and behave similar, but there are subtle conceptual differences in how they are supposed to be used. Don't use them for your basic app navigation, but rather for switching between similar "things".

If you want to employ this on device pre-3.0 though, you will have to use ActionBarSherlock. It does work fine and we're using it in several projects, so if you're having problems integrating it I suggest creating a new question for that, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: This all make sense, however is this activity going to be the only activity in my application because it seems to me that if I had other activities I would lose this action bar? Just doesnt seem to be the correct/modular way to go about it and I'm sure it will start getting messy.